# iPhone:Google Place API Key & Data problem

Tags: iphone

I am working with google place api and I tried so much but google place api does not provided Indian Data. Does google place api provided Indian Data? If yes then please send me any link or any idea to develop this functionality. My google api key will expire after 24hours so Is there any way to increase time limit??

I want to develop following type of map application in iPhone.

[image][image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: no i am not using gdata parser

Comment: did you get any solution ? We are also facing same issue.

Comment: @Jennis ya remove types parameter and add parameter name=restaurant so you got the Indian Data

Comment: Thax a lot buddy for sharing this. You can post that as your answer and accept so that all people get idea. Once again thax.